# Inner product - change of axioms

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we retain the first three axioms for a real inner product

$1.~\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$

$2.~\langle x,y+z\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle$

$3.~c\langle x,y\rangle=\langle cx,y\rangle$

but replace the fourth axiom by a new axiom:

$4'.~\langle x,x\rangle=0~$ iff $~x=0$

Prove that either

$\langle x,x\rangle>0,~\forall x\neq0$

or

$\langle x,x\rangle<0,~\forall x\neq0$

Now there is a hint which suggest that I should assume that $\langle x,x\rangle>0$ for some $x\neq0$ and $\langle y,y\rangle<0$ for some $y\neq0$. Then I need to find and element $z\neq0$ in a space spanned by $\{x,y\}$ with $\langle z,z\rangle=0$.

So my idea is as follows: assume $0$ belongs to the space spanned by $\{x,y\}$ (otherwise - result follows trivially). If it does, it means that there exists $c_1$ and $c_2$ not both equal to zero such that

$$c_1x+c_2y=0$$

As a result there also exists inner product in this space equal to zero, where $z\neq0$ but $\langle z,z\rangle=0$. But then we have a contradiction to the $4'$ axiom.

Could this work as a proof? If not, what do I need to turn it into proof or how should I approach this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: you mean $\langle y,y \rangle < 0$ ?

Comment: yes, sorry! fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "assume $0$ belongs to the space spanned by $\{x,y\}$": the span of any set of vectors is a vector subspace, and thus necessarily contains $0$. The rest of your argument also looks muddled to me (unless I misunderstood it).

Here is what I suggest: you are assuming that you have vectors $v$ and $w$ with

$\langle v, v \rangle = c_1 > 0$, 
$\langle w,w \rangle = c_2 < 0$.

Now try to evaluate $\langle av + bw, av +bw \rangle$ for arbitrary $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Your answer will come out in terms of $a,b,c_1,c_2$ and $\langle v, w \rangle$.  Then show that you can choose $a$ and $b$, not both zero, so as to get $\langle av+bw,av+bw \rangle = 0$.

**Aside**: This can be viewed as a question on elementary quadratic form theory: show that a real quadratic form is either positive definite, negative definite, or isotropic.  Since every nondegenerate real quadratic form can be diagonalized with $\pm 1$ coefficients, it comes down to observing that if we have $x^2-y^2$ as a subform then we must be isotropic.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what it means to evaluate <ax +bw,ax+bw> given that you don't know what the inner product is.

Comment: @larry: As it says in the answer, one can express the inner product in terms of $a,b,c_1,c_2,\langle v, w \rangle$.  If you have a question about this material, feel free to ask it on this site.

Comment: I'm just not sure how knowing that you can choose a,b, not zeros, s.t. <av+bw,av+bw> = 0 helps you prove <x,x> >0 or <x,x> $<0$ for all x $neq$ 0.

Comment: @larry: We are assuming that if sometimes the inner product is positive and sometimes it is negative, then it is necessarily always zero for at least one nonzero $x$.  Applying 4' we get a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how you can choose a,b to force <z,z> = 0

Comment: @larry: (In my last comment "assuming" should be replaced by "showing".)  Please ask a new question if you are interested.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I did. Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675695/prove-x-x-0-or-x-x-0-for-all-x-neq-0

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I don't see what is confusing you. I ask how do you choose a,b. How do you? Will you answer that?