# Prove $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$ or $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$

Tags: inner-products

[**Added by PLC**: This question is a followup to [this already answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298870/inner-product-change-of-axioms/298891).]

Keep the axioms for a real inner product (symmetry, linearity, and homogeneity). 
But make the fourth be
$$\langle x,x \rangle = 0 \text{ if and only if } x = 0.$$

I want to prove that either $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ or $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Note: $c_1 = \langle x,x \rangle > 0$ and and $c_2 = \langle y,y \rangle < 0$.

Here's the sketch of the proof I want: Assume $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ for some $x$ and $\langle y,y \rangle < 0$ for some $y$. I'm trying to find a $z \neq 0$ such that $\langle z,z\rangle = 0$, where $z$ is in the space spanned by $\{x,y\}$. By contradiction, we know that $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$ or $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Unfortunately, my proof doesn't work that way, and I don't think it proves what I want it to prove.

I say let $\langle z,z \rangle = \langle ax + by, ax + by\rangle$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\langle z,z \rangle = a^2 \langle x,x \rangle + 2ab \langle x,y \rangle + b^2 \langle y,y \rangle = 0.$$
Let $a = \langle y,y \rangle$ and $b = \langle x,x \rangle$. 
After plugging $a$ and $b$ in, I get: 
\begin{align*}
& \langle y,y \rangle + 2\langle x,y \rangle + \langle x,x \rangle\langle y,y \rangle = 0 \\
\implies& c_2 + 2 \langle x,y \rangle + c_1 c_2 = 0 \\
\implies& 2\langle x,y \rangle = -(c_1 c_2 + c_2).
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\langle z,z\rangle=
&= c_1 c_2 + 2(-c_1 c_2 - c_2) + c_1 c_2 \\
&= -2c_1c_2 + 2(c_1c_2 c_2) \\
&= -c_1c_2+c_1c_2 +c_2 = 0
\end{align*}
Then $c_2 = 0$

The only thing I can think to do now is to claim a contradiction: we said $c_2 < 0$. But I don't think this proves what we want to prove that either $\langle x,x \rangle < 0$ OR $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

I think my issue is that I don't know how to choose $a,b$ to make $\langle z,z \rangle = 0$. Someone please offer some help.

Comment: Please: Write $\langle z,z\rangle=\langle ax+by,ax+by\rangle$, not $<z,z>=< ax+by,ax+by>$.  That is standard.

Comment: You seem to be confused by the notation: $a$ and $b$ are used for two different things at different points in your computation, and $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not defined.  If you sort this out, then what you are trying to do should work.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark $a,b$ are not used for two different things. $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we get to pick values for $a,b$. And then we need to show that the inner product of <z,z> = 0 given these values of $a,b$.

Comment: @larry: In your question, you first introduce $a$ and $b$ as *variable* coefficients of $x$ and $y$, then you say that $\langle x, x \rangle = a$, $\langle y, y \rangle = b$.  Later still you use $c_1$ and $c_2$, which you haven't defined, but seem to want $c_1 = \langle x,x \rangle$, $c_2 = \langle y, y \rangle$.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. $a$ and $b$ are variable. I'm allowed to pick a value for them. That is because ultimately they are defined by x and y are.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark "Then show that you can choose a and b, not both zero, so as to get ⟨av+bw,av+bw⟩=0." I'm asking you how to choose $a,b$.

Comment: @Dror: The use of `<` and `>` instead of `\langle` and `\rangle` means that some of the text (and the axiom) is being swallowed by the HTML parser. I’m editing to fix it.

Comment: Guys is it just me being tired? Or is this an attempt to prove one direction of the 4th axiom?

Comment: @larry: You want $a$ and $b$ to be variable, yes, but then you are setting them equal to $\langle x, x \rangle$ and $\langle y, y \rangle$.  These are not necessarily values which make $\langle ax+by,ax+by \rangle = 0$.  And what are $c_1$ and $c_2$ in your question?  Anyway, I have now answered this question twice (and Berci has also given you a correct anwer): it is time for you to reflect on the information you've been given.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark can you *please* explain to me, what's the difference between the goal and one direction of the 4th axiom?

Comment: @Dror: The goal is to show that if $V$ is a real vector space and $\langle, \rangle: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a symmetric bilinear form on $V$, then if there is $x \in V$ with $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ and $y \in V$ with $\langle y,y \rangle < 0$ then there is $0 \neq z \in V$ with $\langle z,z \rangle = 0$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark wouldn't $(z \neq 0) \land (\langle z , z \rangle = 0)$ violate the 4th axiom written above? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dror: Yes, so contrapositively: under the fourth axiom, one cannot have $x$ and $y$ with $\langle x, x \rangle > 0$ and $\langle y,y \rangle < 0$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I just realized how I'm supposed to interpret the goal.. Need to clarify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\langle x, x \rangle > 0$ and $\langle y, y \rangle < 0$.  I claim that there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ax+by \neq 0$ and  $\langle ax+by, ax+by \rangle = 0$.  This shows that if 
$q(v) = \langle v, v \rangle$ assumes both positive and negative value, then there is some nonzero $v$ with $q(v) = 0$.

We have $\langle ax+by, ax+by \rangle = a^2 \langle x,x \rangle + 2ab \langle x,y \rangle + b^2 \langle y,y \rangle$.  If we view this as a quadratic equation in $a$, its discriminant is

$\Delta = 4b^2 \langle x,y \rangle^2 - 4 b^2 \langle x,x \rangle \langle y, y \rangle$.

Because of the assumptions on the sign of $\langle x,x \rangle$ and $\langle y, y \rangle$, $\Delta > 0$ when $b \neq 0$.  So choose your favorite nonzero value of $b$; then the quadratic formula shows that the equation $\langle ax+by,ax+by \rangle = 0$ can be solved for $a$.

Comment: I don't see where you are getting your discriminant.

Comment: @larry: The discriminant of the quadratic $Aa^2 +Ba+ C$ is $B^2-4AC$.

Comment: @larry: When you compute the discriminant of $\langle x,x \rangle a^2 + (2b \langle x,y \rangle) a + (b^2 \langle y, y \rangle)$, what do you get?

Comment: As long as b $\neq$ 0, then the entire quadratic expression is positive? Are you referring to the discriminant or the quad. equation when you say "this expression" in the last paragraph?

Comment: No, when the discriminant of $f(a) = Aa^2+Ba+C$ is positive, $f(a)$ has two real roots and is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.

Answer (score 2):

We can assume by scaling that $\langle x,x\rangle =1$ and $\langle y,y\rangle=-1$.

The method should work: let $z=x+\lambda y$. Then we have
$$\langle z,z\rangle\ =\ 1+2\lambda\langle x,y\rangle-\lambda^2$$
which has a real root in $\lambda$, as $\langle x,y\rangle$ is considered constant (given).

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: $\langle y, y \rangle  = -1$ is nonsense even with these different axioms.

Comment: @Squirtle: I believe that Berci's answer is correct.  Why do you say that $\langle y,y \rangle = -1$ is "nonsense"?

Comment: @larry: For $\lambda=\frac{-2\langle x,y\rangle\pm\sqrt{4\langle x,y\rangle^2+4}}{-2}$ we get the required $\langle z,z\rangle=0$.

Comment: What is scaling part about?

Comment: Pick a $y_0$ which has $\langle y_0,y_0\rangle<0$, then consider its length as $r:=\sqrt{-\langle y_0,y_0\rangle}$, and let $y:=y_0/r$. Then $$\langle y,y\rangle=\frac{\langle y_0,y_0\rangle}{r^2}=-1\,.$$

Comment: why is there a - under the sqrt?

Comment: else $r$ would be imaginary

Comment: So I see what you are doing, but I really don't want to use this answer. I want to see how to choose and $a,b$ to make <z,z> =0.